# sudo apt-get update gives error

Tags: sudo, apt-get

sudo apt-get update gives error
W: http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/PMM_0.1.10/dists/trusty/InRelease: Signature by key 8BADC1A02FC9C07FB8C20EC0BD11A6AA914BDF7E uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/PHP_5.2/dists/trusty/InRelease: Signature by key 8BADC1A02FC9C07FB8C20EC0BD11A6AA914BDF7E uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/PHP_5.3/dists/trusty/InRelease: Signature by key 8BADC1A02FC9C07FB8C20EC0BD11A6AA914BDF7E uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://autoinstall.plesk.com/ubuntu/PHP_5.4/dists/trusty/InRelease: Signature by key 8BADC1A02FC9C07FB8C20EC0BD11A6AA914BDF7E uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is just a warning and not an error. The update is still happening.

If you want to upgrade, you'll have to use `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get install --only-upgrade <packagename>`

Answer (score 0):

Kali users should have these entries in their /etc/apt/sources.list file:

Enter web site: [enter link description here](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories)
Now copy The Kali Rolling Repository

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

deb http://old.kali.org/kali sana main non-free contrib

deb http://old.kali.org/kali moto main non-free contrib
```

Terminal:

> apt-get update

```
apt-get upgrade
```